# Solr core URL / Typo3

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, typo3, tomcat6

Goodday,

I've installed Solr 4.8 on a Debian server with the `install-solr.sh` provided by Typo3. After the script I added some extra cores to the `solr.xml` and the admin UI displays them, that they are running.

The thing is, Typo3 needs a url (path) to connect to solr. Everywhere on the internet they say `http://{host}:{port}/solr/{core}`. Whenever i put this in my browser (`http://{host}:8080/solr/don_nl/`) it'll display a 404.

Did i forget something when configurering solr?

Contents solr.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr persistent="false">
    <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
        <core name="core_en" instanceDir="typo3cores" schema="english/schema.xml" dataDir="data/core_en" />
        <core name="core_nl" instanceDir="typo3cores" schema="dutch/schema.xml" dataDir="data/core_nl" />
        <core name="core_de" instanceDir="typo3cores" schema="dutch/schema.xml" dataDir="data/core_de" />
        <core name="don_nl" instanceDir="typo3cores" schema="dutch/schema.xml" dataDir="data/don_nl" />
        <core name="wow_nl" instanceDir="typo3cores" schema="dutch/schema.xml" dataDir="data/wow_nl" />
    </cores>
</solr>
```

**EDIT**

Whenever i go to : `http://{host}:8080/solr/don_nl/select/?q=*%3A*`, i get the following response.

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":31,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

Typo3 Solr configuration:

```
plugin.tx_solr {
    solr {
            scheme = http
            host = **********
            port = 8080
            path = /solr/don_nl/
        }
```

And this is the result (in Report).

[image: My result in Typo3]

Comment: Give us an example of the URL you're putting in your browser (you can anonymize the hostname).

Comment: Hey Jozef, i've added it to my question. `http://{host}:8080/solr/don_nl/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response you're getting from `http://{host}:8080/solr/don_nl/select/?q=*%3A*` seems to be OK, so the Solr URL (of the `don_nl` core) is `http://{host}:8080/solr/don_nl` - but there is nothing to see in the URL of the core, as it's just a base for the other services of the core. But you can use it for Typo3 configuration.

If you want to see the Solr GUI, go to `http://{host}:8080/solr/`.

Comment: The result of adding the url to Typo3 are now in my question. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are both systems (Typo3 and Solr) on the same server? If yes, try to use `http://localhost:8080/solr/don_nl`, if not, check, if the Solr url is accessible from the Typo3 server (e.g. using `wget` or `curl` from the commandline). And, of course, check if there isn't a detailed error message in the Typo3's log.

Comment: Thanks to your answer it now connects! Cheers!

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: Somehow our server couldn't connect to the solr one. So with SSH tunneling it went perfectly fine.